# Using Try Catch to log errors, want to send summary e-mail even if errors occurred

Tags: powershell

I'm hoping this isn't a "you can't have your cake and eat it too" scenario.

Currently:

Script runs, performs try/catch for all objects in sources.csv, generates an error log for each failed object.  Does not send e-mail unless ALL objects were successful.

Attempting:

Script runs, performs try/catch for all objects in sources.csv, generates an error log for each failed object.  Sends e-mail showing how many errors occurred and attaches all relevant log files.

```
$clientID = "Blargh Inc"
$intelDir = "C:\Threat Intelligence"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$intelSource = "$($intelDir)\sources.csv"
$intelCount = 0
$intelError = 0

# Begin Email Options
$body = "Threat Intelligence Feed ran for $clientID - "
$subject = "$($clientID) - Threat Intelligence - "
$email = @{
From = "me@mycompany.com"
To = "me@mycompany.com","notme@mycompany.com"
Subject = $subject
SMTPServer = "mail-server.office365.com"
Body = $body
}
# End Email Options

import-Csv $intelSource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
        $storageDir = "$($intelDir)\$($_.threatType) $($_.threatSubtype)"
        $threat = $_.threatType + "_" + $_.threatSubtype    # Set this variable to save headaches passing it later
        $storageFile = "$($storageDir)\$($threat)_$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy)).csv"    # Filename specified by sources.csv fields and today's date
        $url = $_.threatLocation
        # Begin Error Logging
        try {
            $intelCount++
            $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$storageFile)
        }
        catch {
            $intelError++
            $intelErrorMessage = $_.Exception|format-list -force
            echo $intelErrorMessage | Out-File $intelDir\$threat"_ErrorLog_"$(get-date -f MM-dd-yy).txt -Append
            Continue
        }
        # End Error Logging
        # Cleanup
        finally {
            $webclient.Dispose()
        }
        # Throttling (mainly future use with multiple sources)
        Start-Sleep 5
        }
```

The part that is not being processed if any errors occur:

```
if ($intelError -gt 0) {
    $email.Item('Subject') += "$($intelError) Error(s)"
    $email.Item('Body') += "$($intelError) of $($intelCount) sources failed. See attached error log(s)"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $intelDir | Where {$_.Name -match "$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy))"} | foreach{$_.fullname} | Send-MailMessage @email
}
else {
    $email.Item('Subject') += "Success"
    $email.Item('Body') += "No errors"
    Send-MailMessage @email
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added after comment:

Wrap your existing code in another `try`/`finally` block, then put the email code in *that* `finally` block:

```
try {
    import-Csv $intelSource -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
            $storageDir = "$($intelDir)\$($_.threatType) $($_.threatSubtype)"
            $threat = $_.threatType + "_" + $_.threatSubtype    # Set this variable to save headaches passing it later
            $storageFile = "$($storageDir)\$($threat)_$($(get-date -f MM-dd-yy)).csv"    # Filename specified by sources.csv fields and today's date
            $url = $_.threatLocation
            # Begin Error Logging
            try {
                $intelCount++
                $webclient.DownloadFile($url,$storageFile)
            }
            catch {
                $intelError++
                $intelErrorMessage = $_.Exception|format-list -force
                echo $intelErrorMessage | Out-File $intelDir\$threat"_ErrorLog_"$(get-date -f MM-dd-yy).txt -Append
                Continue
            }
            # End Error Logging
            # Cleanup
            finally {
                $webclient.Dispose()
            }
            # Throttling (mainly future use with multiple sources)
            Start-Sleep 5
            }
} finally {
    # email code
}
```

---

Add the email sending parts to your `finally {}` block. The point of that block is to always run the code in there, even if the `catch {}` block was triggered, even if an exception occurred that the `catch` block didn't catch.

Comment: I attempted that but then I get 1 e-mail for each object in sources.csv - a file which will have over 100+ objects by the end of the week.  Defeats the purpose of the summary e-mail and generates a bunch of spam :/

Comment: Hopefully you're still around.  While the extra try/catch guarantees an e-mail is sent, the original try/catch still stops processing objects after the first error encountered (e.g. if sources.csv has 5 objects but the 3rd generates an error, the e-mail states that "1 of 3" failed)

Comment: @ayoungblood I admit I'm not seeing how or why that would happen given the code I'm looking it. I strongly recommend stepping through it and inspecting the code flow and the objects at runtime to see why that might be happening. If you can't find it that way it may be worthy of a new question.

Comment: the directories didn't exist.  I've now added an `If` with a `Test-Path` and `mkdir` *sigh*  It's one thing after another with this script :P  For example, now the site I'm downloading from is just redirecting to its homepage for all invalid queries

Comment: @ayoungblood I don't know what version of PowerShell you're using, but if it's 3 or higher, use `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of the web client object. You can tell it not to follow a redirect and then test the response to see what the code is. That would allow you to throw an exception and let your existing catch handle it. Of course you could do this with .net objects too, I just don't know remember how offhand.

Comment: This particular client site is limited to 2.0, sorry if I'm over-picking your brain (obviously, I'm very new to powershell).  It was working up until the site-owner changed his handling for invalid url's.  I tried forcing the test using bogus addresses altogether but "The remote name could not be resolved" is causing the exact same issue (1 of 3 failed vs 1 of 5 failed).

Comment: @ayoungblood I can't really say why, you need to step through the code live in PowerShell ISE. When you can see the code executing line by line you should be able to tell why it's not seeing or going through all 5. This is really starting to sound like you should post a new question though.